# How can I replace an entire line containing a string?

Tags: bash

Say I have a file called file.txt that contains

```
abc
post_max_size = 100M
def
```

I need a script that will find the line containing post_max_size and replace the entire line with post_max_size = 50M. So it will result as:

```
abc
post_max_size = 50M
def
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
[me@home]$ cat file.txt 
abc
post_max_size = 100M
def

[me@home]$ sed -i 's/.*post_max_size.*/post_max_size = 50M/' file.txt 
[me@home]$ cat file.txt
abc
post_max_size = 50M
def
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks. sed scares me it always looks to me like someone mashed the keyboard

Comment: @TomHare: ...wait till you meet [Perl](http://99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-perl-737.html). By the way, you should usually use single quotes around the `sed` script.